# Exception thrown error at runtime when writing to object

Tags: c++, visual-c++-runtime

I've been sitting here for hours trying to figure this out. I haven't been able to find a similar problem (although I'm sure it has been done). So on to my question. When I compile this, it is fine.
  I should add that unsortedList is Book*, which is a struct.

```
string tit = tempBook->title;
string act = tempBook->action;
string aut = tempBook->author;
string sub = tempBook->subject;
char* tm = tempBook->time;

unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].title;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].action;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].author;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].subject;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].time;
```

However, when I compile this, I receive an error:
Exception thrown at 0x5AC6516F (vcruntime140d.dll) in Assign.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

```
string tit = tempBook->title;
string act = tempBook->action;
string aut = tempBook->author;
string sub = tempBook->subject;
char* tm = tempBook->time;

unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].title = tit;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].action = act;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].author = aut;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].subject = sub;
unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].time = tm;
```

And then it pops up window memcpy.asm with the cursor at this location:

```
CopyUpByteLoop:
    mov     al, byte ptr [esi]
    mov     byte ptr [edi], al
    inc     esi
    inc     edi
    dec     ecx
    jne     CopyUpByteLoop
```

The definition of struct Book as requested:

```
    struct Book
{
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    std::string subject;
    char* time;
    std::string action;
};
```

Here is the complete function:

```
    void DB::insertBook(Book* tempBook)
{
    using namespace std;
    unsortedArrayLength++;
    string tit = tempBook->title;
    string act = tempBook->action;
    string aut = tempBook->author;
    string sub = tempBook->subject;
    char* tm = tempBook->time;

    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].title = tit;
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].action = act;
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].author = aut;
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].subject = sub;
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].time = tm;

    system("cls");

    cout << "You have " << unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].action <<":\n" << endl <<
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].title << endl <<
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].author << endl <<
    unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].subject << endl <<
    "on " << unsortedList[unsortedArrayLength].time << endl << endl;

    printToLog(tempBook);
}
```

Please help Obi-Wan. You're my only hope...

Comment: Is your variable 'unsortedArrayLength' a constant? If not, you could be having issues with the array being properly initialised. Actually, also looking at that, I'm not sure why you would be using the array length variable as an index. That would return you 1 index past the end of the array, which is a classic 'off by one' error. You may need to post more information about the way that you designed your array and the way that you're indexing it.

Comment: I was just going to edit that unsortedList is of type Book*. My index == 1. There is 1 object at index from a previous operation in another function.

Comment: Please include the definition of struct Book.

Comment: I'm still hung up on the unsortedArrayLength variable. How is it handled, and if you're using a pointer as a dynamic array of structs, what are you doing to unsortedArrayLength in order to use it as an index?

Comment: It is being incremented before the code begins, as the index position before the code runs is: unsortedArrayLength = 0. As the compiler enters this function, unsortedArrayLength++; is the line before this code.

Comment: Try providing an MCVE (i.e. a small sample of code that someone else can compile/link/run to reproduce your problem) rather than a few disconnected pieces of code.   As is, there are many possible explanations for your problem, and you haven't provided enough information to pick which one(s) actually are the problem.   In short:  you have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I made the instantiation of the array bigger. It appeared I was hitting the upper bounds of the array. The array was initialized with 2, which I though would be enough, but however it was not. :( Thank you to all lent me their knowledge.

Comment: Instead of randomly guessing at an appropriate array size, why don't you join the 21st Century and use a `std::vector` that will actually grow as needed?

Comment: We haven't reached vectors in class yet. We're making sorted lists at the moment. My professor actually mentioned that if you fill up one array, you can programmatically create another one, but he didn't elaborate on how to do this. With the due date of the assignment approaching, I didn't look into it. :/